# What is the fastest and most reliable way to split a 50GB binary file into chunks of 5GB or less, and then reassemble it later?

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Our servers are running Ubuntu Linux, and the binary file is a BSON dump of a large MongoDB collection. How reliable is a tool like `split`? Is there a faster or better way to do this?

Answer (score 41):

`split` is very reliable. We use it for porting large log files, and it worked well for up to a couple of GBs (not 50 gb anyway).

I believe you can try using the split for your requirement, and let us know.

**Split into 5GB files**

```
split --bytes=5G inputfile
```

It will split into multiple files of 5GB and name it as xaa, xab, xac, .... and so on.

**Concatenate**

```
cat x* > outfile
```

by this you can concatenate as single file in the other end.

Comment: On OS X I had to use split -b50m to make 50 megabyte files. Note no equals sign, note lowercase.

Comment: On OS X I have to give explicitly the output file name: `split -b3m file.zip file.zip` otherwise `split` creates files called `xaa`, `xab`, etc.

Comment: On macOS `11.6.3`, I did `split -b 4000000k /path/to/input_file`

Comment: My edit attempt to change the quotes to code (commands) was rejected. If someone could kindly do that this answer would look prettier. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd rather see `split --bytes=5G inputfile` and `cat x* > outfile` as code than as quotes.

Comment: how does cat ensure the order? I guess it orders lexically?

Answer (score 34):

To split, [split -b](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)

To join, just `cat`.

AFAIK they are completely reliable, and I doubt there is something more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

`split` & `cat` are totally reliable.  You can additionally compress in-line like this.  Suppose your input file is `dump.bson`:

```
gzip < dump.bson | split -b 32M - dump.bson.gz.
```

And then reconstitute with this:

```
cat dump.bson.gz.* | gunzip > dump.bson
```

Tip, this works just as well with `xz(dec)` in place of `g(un)zip`

Answer (score 4):

If you have rar installed, it's worked very well for me:

**To Separate**

```
rar a -m0 -v5000m newfilename giantfile.foo
```

- a = add files to archive
- m0 = no compression
- v5000m = split into chunks of 5000 megabytes

**To Reassemble**

Start with the first part. The rest will be found automatically:

```
unrar x newfilename.part1.tar
```

- x = extract

**Benefits:**

- CRC on the content of the split archive,
- split-file ordering kept automatically,
- multiple files and dirs can be included.

Answer (score 1):

From your question one could assume, that between the split phase and the reassemble phase there might be a transport phase - in this case a process, that involves compression could be quite beneficial.

The standard GNU `tar` has the `-M` option to create multi-volume archives and the `-L` option to define the length of a segment. Together with one of the compression options (e.g. `-z`,`j`, ...) you could create a toolchain, that

- comes with every Linux distro I know of
- provides splitting, reassembly, compression and decompression
- has the additional benefit of being able to pack more than one file into a single archive sequence (e.g. the MongoDB data folder as-is)